# c++ manipulating a vector of Elements

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, polymorphism

I am looking for the ideal way to work on a Vector (delete,add) but also be able to make a comparison between elements

somthing likes this:

```
[first]...[i-1][i][i+1]...[j]...[last] <-vector
```

if condition is met in a comparison with i&j then do the following:

```
[first]...[X][X][X][i*]...[j]...[last] <-vector
```

where X is a deleted element (in our case i-1,i,i+1) and i* is the replacing element.
now I know the distance between i and j is 2.

as far as I know (new to c++), there is 2 ways handling this. either using a direct approach to the vector (`myVec.at(i).func()>myVec.at(j).func()`) but then it seems you are limited because funcs like erase & insert depending on an iterator.

the other way is using iterator, but the comparison (i & j) seems to envolve to much movement on the vector. for example, compare i and j (require me to move the iterator to j? ,assuming I dont want another iterator), and deleting 3 elements, need to move back to i-1 to pull the element etc'.

I guess that you mix but it looks awful:

```
if(distance(myVec->begin(),it)+2<myVec->size() || ((Operation*) (*it))->Precedence() >= ((Operation*) myVec->at(distance(myVec->begin(),it)+2))->Precedence());
```

the above code is example for a simple if that first check that j is in the vector's range, and if not compare i and j, (i with iterator, j with std::distance).

Comment: Is the next possible occurrence after 'j' or is there some recurrence?

Comment: Vector iterators are very cheap to construct, since the memory used for the vector is guaranteed to be contiguous it's basically a pointer addition. If you want to remove element `i`, you can do `myVec.erase(myVec.begin() + i);`.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are guaranteed contiguous memory, dealing with indexing them is thus very cheap. The following is perfectly acceptable:

```
//assuption: i, i-1 and i+1 are all valid vector elements
if(i + 2 < vec.size() && condition(vec[i], vec[i+2]))
{
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + (i-1), vec.begin() + (i + 1));
}
```

All indexing operations above are straightforward pointer arithmetic: you do not need to worry about overheads on any iterator creation involved